# How to handle a change in a custom GridItemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, event-handling, dataprovider

I'm using a `DataGrid` in one of my project, with a custom `ItemRenderer` for one of the column to represent a boolean value as a `CheckBox`

```
<s:DataGrid id="clients" resizableColumns="false">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="fullName" headerText="Client name" />
            <s:GridColumn dataField="active" headerText="Active?" width="90"
                          itemRenderer="CheckBoxGridItemRenderer"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

And here is the code of `CheckBoxGridItemRenderer`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                    clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {
                checkBox.selected = Boolean(data[column.dataField]);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:CheckBox id="checkBox" horizontalCenter="0" />

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

Now here is my question: What is the best way to handle the change in data from the class I declared the `DataGrid` ?

I tried to change the data value from within my custom item renderer class:

```
private function valueChange():void
{
    data.active = checkBox.selected;
}

[...]

<s:CheckBox id="checkBox" change="valueChange()" />
```

and then listen to `CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE` event on the dataProvider of the DataGrid but I never handle any change. Any thoughts or advices?

Comment: So, you want to change the data from within the DataGrid? Try adding `rendererIsEditable="true"` to the column.

Comment: This doens't change anything. FYI I am already able to change the `CheckBox` value without it. But I would like to handle the related event outside of my ItemRenderer, i.e in the class where the `DataGrid` is instantiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found a solution to my problem, I will post it here, but I leave the question open for some time in case someone come up with a better one.

First I created a `CustomEvent` (I could use the `CollectionEvent` class but this way I'm sure I don't mess up with the internal logic of the `DataGrid`)

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class CustomEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const CHANGE:String = "change";

        public var column:String;
        public var data:Object;

        public function CustomEvent(column:String, data:Object)
        {
            super(CHANGE, true);
            this.column = column;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the call to `super()` with `bubbles` set to true. This is actually needed for the event to be handle here.

Then I modified my `CheckBoxGridItemRenderer` to dispatch this event when the checkbox is selected/deselected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import CustomEvent;

            override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {
                if (data)
                {
                    checkBox.selected = Boolean(data[column.dataField]);
                }
            }

            private function valueChange():void
            {
                data[column.dataField] = checkBox.selected;
                dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(column.dataField, data));
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:CheckBox id="checkBox" horizontalCenter="0" change="valueChange()" />
</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

Finally I only have to listen to my custom event dispatched by the `DataGrid` instance:

```
clients.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CHANGE, handleCustomEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you change the data. When an element of data collection changed, the DataGrid can detect nothing unless you dispatch CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE for the data collection.
In addition, the data collection should be something like ArrayCollection, not Array.

Comment: The dataProvider of the DataGrid is set elsewhere in the code and it is an ArrayCollection, but this has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE must be dispatched to the data provider, or valueChanged() will never run.

Comment: If you talk about the `valueChange()` method I added in my custom `ItemRenderer`, this method is called with success whenever I click on the `CheckBox`

Comment: Sorry, i made mistakes. Try to override **set data** function instead of **prepare**. Don't forget to call super.data.

Comment: I need to override `prepare` in order to assign the correct initial value from the data source to my checkbox. On the other hand I don't have anything to do in an override of `set data` except calling the `super` method. Maybe my question is not clear enough. I posted an answer that might help clarifying it